# highcharts using pie chart plotOptions

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I am using high chart version 6.1.1. in pie plot option data labels I am using  **alignTo: 'plotEdges',** property. it not working when I change to version 7.1.2 is working fine. is there any workaround for  **alignTo: 'plotEdges',** in version 6.1.1. can you check the below snippets

version 6.1.1 ---> `enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/qx0a65yh/

version 7.1.2 ---> `enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/9xchk5bt/

can please help me

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround. The `alignTo` feature is available for versions > 7.0.0.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.alignTo

Comment: hi, thank you for replay Sebastian Wędzel . in > 7.0.0 it works fine. I need the same property behavior in version 6.1.1.

Comment: Each Highcharts version has new features or fixed bugs - that's why they have been released. This feature is available for versions > 7.0.0. because it has been developed on this specific version. If you want to use it you need to buy a license for a newer version or try to implement it by yourself.